# WCF REST Resource Design - POSTing vs. GETing

Tags: wcf, rest

I am designing a REST service for my company. No one here has had much experience with REST so I read through a few books on the subject but I am stuck on resource design of a POST vs. the resource design of a GET request for the same data. Particularly in the case of foreign relationships.

For instance I have a class PurchaseRequest which represents a request to purchase some fixed asset. Behind the scenes my service is an interface to a relational DB. There is a PURCHASE_REQUEST table which has a foreign key to an ASSET table (Defining which of a fixed list of assets are being requested) and a PERSON table (Defining which of the users is doing the requesting). Currently in my service when a GET command is issued for a purchase request, the service returns the whole thing: An XML representation of the PURCHASE_REQUEST table entry along with a list of asset entries like so:

```
<PurchaseRequest>
    <ID></ID>
    <RequestDate></RequestDate>
    <Requestor href="/requestors/requestorID">
        <RequestorID></RequestorID>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <LastName></LastName>
    </Requestor>
    <RequestedAssets>
        <RequestedAsset href="/assets/AssetNumber" >
            <AssetNumber></AssetNumber>
            <Year></Year>
            <Make></Make>
            <Model></Model>
            <Cost></Cost>
        </RequestedAsset>
        <RequestedAsset href="/assets/AssetNumber" >
            <AssetNumber></AssetNumber>
            <Year></Year>
            <Make></Make>
            <Model></Model>
            <Cost></Cost>
        </RequestedAsset>
        <RequestedAsset href="/assets/AssetNumber" >
            <AssetNumber></AssetNumber>
            <Year></Year>
            <Make></Make>
            <Model></Model>
            <Cost></Cost>
        </RequestedAsset>
    </RequestedAssets>
</PurchaseRequest>
```

This works pretty efficiently. The consuming application makes a single request and gets the whole thing and links to the full resource requestor resource or asset resource if they need them.

The problem comes on a POST. My gut tells me to try to use the same resource layout for POSTing a new purchase request as I used to retrieve an existing one. This is what all the examples in the books I have read do anyway. I don’t need to know anything more than the Asset Number and Requestor ID to fulfill the POST. That means that data is not necessary but the inefficiency alone is not what bothers me. The main thing is you should not be able to edit the year, make or model of an asset when creating a purchase request, those fields are pre-defined. You also should be able to create a new asset definition when creating a purchase request. Similarly you should not be able to update/create a person's details when creating a purchase request. There are separate services for creating/updating people and assets.

The only thing I can think of is to define a different DataContract class for the POST which has the minimum info to identify an asset or a person and does not expose those fields which cannot be updated. I really don’t love this option because it is going to create a large number of DataContracts  classes (nearly all of the tables in my DB have foreign relationships, this is not isolated to one request or I would not be worrying about it) However I really don’t love my current design because REST does not have read-only fields.The burden is now on the consumers of my service to constantly be checking,  "does it save this field… what about this one?..." Has anyone else ran into this issue? Is it common to have to define a separate DataContract class for POSTing and GETing? Seems like a pretty basic design question but I don’t see a lot of posts out there on the subject so I am hoping I just missed something. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider using OData to do this?

Comment: Microsoft doesn't recommend using WCF for REST services anymore. I would take a look at ASP.NET Web API (http://www.asp.net/web-api), which is going to make things a lot simpler for you. No need to worry about data contracts and all of the configuration involved with WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will have to do some research into both OData and Web-API. Can you explain how either of these technologies would help fix the issue? After a (very) quick look at Web-API it seemed like I would still need separate classes for POST/PUT commands vs. GET commands leaving me in the same place.

Comment: After some review I don't think using MS Web-API or OData actually answers this question. What I want to know is should a response resource look the same as a request resource? Is it un-RESTful to have the POST/PUT request resource just have key values to identify that a resource is related to another, while having the GET response resource contain the details of the related resource? It is not really an implementation-technology question but rather really a REST design question. Any input will be appreciated.